# One Kubernetes Ingress to front multiple clusters? Scope issues

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

So I have two clusters at the moment (soon to be a few more, once I get this working), ClusterA and ClusterB.

Is it possible for one ingress to interface with services from both clusters?

ClusterA hosts the front end and the ingress, while ClusterB hosts the back end.

The excerpted ingress is below. Everything bar the back end works.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:{...}  
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/test-frontend-ingress
  uid: //
  spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: idu-frontend-XYZ
    servicePort: 80
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: test-backend-app-service
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /api/v2/
      - backend:
          serviceName: idu-frontend-XYZ
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
  tls:
  - secretName: tls-cert-name
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 123.456.789.012
```

Back end service URL:
`https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/service/asia-southeast1-b/test-backend/default/test-backend-app-service...`

URL the ingress tries to point to:
`https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/service/asia-southeast1-b/standard-cluster-1/default/test-backend-app-service...`

So what I've gathered is the ingress can only interface with things in the same cluster as them? `test-backend` and `standard-cluster-1` are the cluster names, and they are both on the default namespace. Isn't that kind of pointless, as you can only deploy one thing to each cluster? Unless your images contain multiple apps, in which case it isn't really microservices anymore.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't deploy everything to one cluster?

Comment: I wanted to give the back end more vCPUs per node, and the backend can have relatively low powered nodes. If I deploy everything to one cluster, my understanding was I can't choose the type of machine each deployment gets.

Comment: You can add different node pools. On GKE it's really easy - just edit your cluster, and add a second node pool. You can use labels on the node, and nodeAffinity on the pods to ensure they get scheduled on nodes in the right pool. We're using 2 node pools in our transcoding cluster: the first contains 2 1-CPU machines which host the queue processor pods, and the other is a autoscaling cluster of 4 CPU machines which actually run the transcoding jobs. We use taints, labels, and nodeAffinity to ensure the right pods get scheduled on the right nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting two clusters with Kubernetes is hard I guess.

Instead you can deploy both the services on the same cluster. You can create two deployments and expose them as services. And then ingress can redirect traffic between them.

Why do you need a cluster per service though ?

If there is no other alternative you will have to do something like this: 
https://appscode.com/products/voyager/7.1.1/guides/ingress/http/external-svc/

Comment: Seems like this might be the way to go! My reasoning, from the other comment:

"I wanted to give the back end more vCPUs per node, and the backend can have relatively low powered nodes. If I deploy everything to one cluster, my understanding was I can't choose the type of machine each deployment gets."

Is there an option of specifying the types of machine needed, per deployment?

Comment: Checkout Resources. That should solve your problem. You can assign how many CPU's and how much memory should be allocated for each pod. You can assign lower values for backend. You can also use node pool affinity to schedule particular kind of workloads on a particular kind of machine.